# The video is not getting played in new tab when web page accessed through mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sample code below to play video in new tab. This works perfectly fine when website accessed through desktop. But the video does not play in different tab when the page is accessed by mobile browser.

```
<html>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Video testing</h1>
        <a href="test.MP4" target="_blank" >
        <video id="test" width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source id="file" src="test.MP4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        </a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var fullscreen = document.getElementById('play-fullscreen'),
  player = document.getElementById('test'),
  _file = document.getElementById('file');

  fullscreen.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (~_file.src.indexOf('?')) 
     player.src = _file.src + '&autoplay=1';
  else player.src = _file.src +'?autoplay=1';

  var req = player.requestFullscreen
    || player.webkitRequestFullscreen
    || player.mozRequestFullScreen
    || player.msRequestFullscreen;
  req.call(player);
  var playPromise = player.play();

  if (playPromise !== undefined) {
    playPromise.then(function() {

    }).catch(function(error) {

    });
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be really helpful if any solution could be given so that it works same way through mobile browser.

Comment: Maybe related to autoplay? Autoplay is disabled on certain mobile clients... ie. it requires user interaction to play.

Comment: In order to protect user's cellular bandwidth, autoplay and preloading are disabled on mobile devices. [https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/](https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/)

Comment: Replace the bitwise 'not' [~] in the if-condition with a valid comparison operator --> !

Comment: I don't think it is related to autoplay. Because the video gets played at the same page instead of new tab. My requirement is there are set of videos in one web page and when I click on particular video that has to be played in new webpage occupying the complete page. It works correctly when accessed through desktop. I don't understand why it is not working the same way in mobile browser.

Comment: Maybe because the mobile client requires interaction (click) on that new tab...

Comment: Perhaps interaction from the page that opened the tab (window.opener) can be used. Do some more digging and testing...